# I'm writing my first plugin and my echo output is showing up on every page of my wordpress installation

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug

I'm using echo and print_r to help with debugging and the output is showing up everywhere. I am using wp_cron and $wpdb as well as regular sql queries. Any idea on why this is happening? I have googled for an answer and I couldn't find anything. This makes me think that I did something wrong if no one else has had this problem.

```
<?php 
/**
* Plugin Name: Automatic Home Descriptions
* Plugin URI: *****************
* Description: this is my plugin
* Author: David Petrey
* Version: 1.0
*/

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) {
/** Set up WordPress environment */
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
}


// $included_files = get_included_files();

// foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
//     echo "$filename\n";
// }


global $wpdb;

//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect(**************************);
//Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo 'connect mysqli <br><br>';


// add custom interval
function add_new_intervals($schedules) 
{
    // add weekly and monthly intervals
    $schedules['desc_update'] = array(
        'interval' => 30,
        'display' => __('Desc_Update')
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_new_intervals');
//echo 'set custom time <br><br>';


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//  Finds out what id's need to be processed
            $d = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT productid FROM homes WHERE populated=' ' AND builder_code !=' '", ARRAY_A); 

            $newids = array();

            foreach($d as $ds){
                foreach ($ds as $k) { 
                    $newids[] = $k;
                    // echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;'; echo $k; echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }; 
            };

echo ' new id\'s '; print_r($newids); echo '<br>';
//echo 'new id\'s <br><br>';



// Random word spinner /////////////////////
$exclude = array();
$sp1 = array('gorgeous', 'stunning', 'beautiful', 'charming', 'exquisite', 'elegant', 'lovely', 'enchanting');
$sp2 = array('home', 'house');
$sp3 = array('spacious', 'roomy', 'comfortable');


        function randWord($ar, $reset) {
            global $exclude;
            global $sp1;
            global $sp2;
            global $sp3;

            if($reset == true){
                $exclude = array();
                //echo 'reset <br><br>';
            }

                //echo '<br><br>===<br><br>';
            $wrdcount = count($ar);
                //echo ' $wrdcount ' . $wrdcount;

            do { $num = rand(0,$wrdcount - 1); } 
            while(in_array($num, $exclude));
                //echo '  $num ' . $num . '  ';

            array_push($exclude, $num);
//echo 'my exclude array '; print_r($exclude); echo '<br>';
//              echo ' <b>rand $exclude</b> '; print_r($ar);
//              echo ' $ar[$num] '.$ar[$num].'<br>';
            return $ar[$num];

        } ///////////////////

//echo 'word spinner <br><br>';


// PULLS OUT ATTRIBUTES //////////////////

        function runfeat ($feat_table, $builder){
            global $wpdb;

            $get_features = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Feature FROM $feat_table WHERE $builder='Y'", ARRAY_A );

            $feat_all = array();
            foreach($get_features as $get_feature){
                array_push($feat_all,$get_feature['Feature']);
            }

            shuffle($feat_all);

            if($feat_table == 'feat_kit'){
                if(count($feat_all) < 8){
                    $need = 8 - count($feat_all);
                    for($a=0; $a < $need; $a++){
                        array_push($feat_all, $feat_all[$a]);
                    }
                }
            }

echo ' inside runfeat ';    print_r($feat_all);

        return $feat_all;

        } ////////////////////

//echo 'grab attributes <br><br>';


// add wp cron task
// add_action( 'hook_name', 'function_name' );
add_action( 'cron_testing', 'builder_task' );

if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_testing' ) ) {
   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'desc_update', 'cron_testing' );
}
// echo 'add cron event <br><br>';

// remove cron task //////////////////////////////////////
// if( false !== ( $time = wp_next_scheduled( 'my_cron' ) ) ) {
//    wp_unschedule_event( $time, 'my_cron' );
// }

// or remove cron task
// $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_testing' );
// wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'cron_testing' );



function builder_task() {
    global $conn;
    global $newids;
    global $wpdb;

    // CREATES NEW ROWS IN home_descriptions  ///////////  LOOP  /////////
//echo 'newids? '; print_r($newids);
//echo 'newids? count '; print_r(count($newids)); echo '<br>';
    for($i=0; $i < count($newids); $i++){
//echo ' <br><br>----------loop to create rows <br>';
        $getbuilder = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT builder_code FROM homes WHERE productid=$newids[$i]", ARRAY_A);
        $builder = $getbuilder['builder_code'];
        echo ' $builder '.$builder.'<br><br>';


echo 'call runfeat <br><br>';
        $kitlist = runfeat('feat_kit', $builder);
        $bathlist = runfeat('feat_bath', $builder);
        $mbathlist = runfeat('feat_mbath', $builder);
echo 'after run feature <br>';
        global $sp1;
        global $sp2;
        global $sp3;

        $spin1 = randWord($sp1, true);
        $spin2 = randWord($sp2, false);
        $spin3 = randWord($sp3, false);
//echo '<br> called word spinner <br><br>';
//echo 'spinner words '.$spin1 .' '. $spin2 .' '. $spin3.'<br>';


        // DOES ROW EXIST?  IF NOT ADD IT 
             $check = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT productid FROM home_descriptions WHERE productid=$newids[$i]", ARRAY_A);
             //if( $check['productid'] == NULL){
//echo '<br><br>check for id if its not there, add it <br><br>'; 
                 $wpdb->insert('home_descriptions', array('productid' => $newids[$i] ));
echo 'bcode '. $builder_code;
                // WRITE TO NEW home_descriptions row  
                $sql = "UPDATE home_descriptions SET spin1 = '$spin1', spin2 = '$spin2', spin3 = '$spin3', kit1 = '$kitlist[0]', kit2 = '$kitlist[1]', kit3 = '$kitlist[2]', kit4 = '$kitlist[3]', kit5 = '$kitlist[4]', kit6 = '$kitlist[5]', kit7 = '$kitlist[6]', kit8 = '$kitlist[7]', bath1 = '$bathlist[0]', bath2 = '$bathlist[1]', bath3 = '$bathlist[2]', mbath1 = '$mbathlist[0]', mbath2 = '$mbathlist[1]', mbath3 = '$mbathlist[2]' WHERE productid = $newids[$i]";

                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    $wpdb->update("homes", array("populated" => 'true'), array( 'productid' => $newids[$i] ));
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }


            //}else{
//              echo '<br><br> already exists'; 
            //}

    }



}


if(count($newids) > 0){
//echo '<h2>--call builder task--</h2><br>';
    builder_task();
}else{
//  echo '<h1>no new id\'s</h1><br>';
}

//echo 'disconnect <br><br>';
mysqli_close($conn);



?>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm sure this code looks terrible

Comment: No worries.  You have to start somewhere.  I'll post an answer that should help with your immediate issue.  For the longterm, I would suggest and object-oriented approach if your plugin will be more than just a few dozen lines of code.  A good boilerplate to start from:  https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but if one unconditionally throws around `echo` statements like you do the results end up in the page.

Comment: You don't need to add a connection to the database. It's already connected. Also, you don't need to load wordpress either. If it's a plugin, it's already loaded.

Comment: I'm used to using console.log for debugging in javascript. I'm new to sql and php. If I put echo in my plugin it is always going to show up on every page in the theme?  In the admin and  everywhere?

Comment: @SteveNorth do I need to close the connnection?  I guess at one point I had this page sitting in the top folder in wordpress. Maybe that's why I thought I had to connect to the database.

Comment: Nope. If you have not opened it you don't need to close it either. Just use the WordPress $wpdb to make your queries if 100% necessary. When i say that, i mean you don't need to do $wpdb if you are querying posts/pages/tax/cat etc. You'd only need to query your own tables if you have any in most cases.

Comment: @DavidPetrey You should never bootstrap WordPress like that, if you need to do `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` then something is terribly wrong. You should also look into custom post types, or at least how to use WPDB instead of raw mysqli. How to do all of these are good questions you can ask on this site, to gain reputation points and learn